# How do different languages implement sorting in their standard libraries?

Tags: c, sorting, programming-languages, standard-library

From what I have (briefly) read, Java and Python both look like they make use of timsort in their standard libaries, while the sorting method in C's stdlib is called qsort because it once was quicksort.

What algorithm do typical languages have implemented in their standard libraries today, and why did they choose that algorithm? Also, did C deviate from quicksort?

I know this question lacks an "actual problem(s) that [I] face" and may seem open ended to some, but knowing how/why certain algorithms are chosen as standard seems pretty useful but relatively untaught. I also feel as though an in depth answer addressing concerns that are language specific (data types?) and machine specific (cache hits?) would provide more insight to how different languages and algorithms work than uni cares to explain.

Answer (score 4):

In [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org), we use [Smooth Sort](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/). Conceptually it's a variant of heap sort (and likewise in-place and O(n log n) time), but it has the nice property that the worst-case performance approaches O(n) for already-sorted or near-sorted input. I'm not convinced it's the best possible choice, but it appears very difficult to do better with an in-place algorithm with O(n log n) worst-case.

Being a little-known invention of Dijkstra's also makes it kind of cool. :-)

Comment: I need to spend some time reading about musl and smooth sort now! Just skimming both pages got me pretty interested. Smooth sort looks pretty nice, interesting algorithm too.

Answer (score 1):

C does not specificy the algorithm to be used by `qsort`.

On current glibc (2.17) `qsort` allocates memory (using `malloc` or `alloca` if memory required is really small) and uses merge sort algorithm. If memory requirements are too high or if `malloc` fails it uses quicksort algorithm.

Comment: I suspect it still uses introsort, not plain quicksort, in the failure case. But I haven't checked.

Comment: Well I checked and as far as I understood the code, it is quicksort. Also for information their quicksort implementation uses a simple insertion sort when the partition is small (< 4 elements).

Comment: Introsort is glibc's quicksort variant that tracks the ratio of successive partition sizes to detect when it might be getting into an O(n²) worst-case, and switch to heapsort in that case. I wonder why they use insertion-sort for small partitions though... doing the leaves with sorting networks should be a lot better.

Comment: The source file mentions 4 optimization to quicksort discussed by Sedgewick but none seems to refer to this. Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

My machine's C library provides `qsort`, `heapsort`, and `mergesort`, saying in the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/qsort.3.html):

> The **`qsort()`** and **`qsort_r()`** functions are an implementation of C.A.R.  Hoare's "quicksort" algorithm, a variant of partition-exchange sorting; in particular, see D.E.
>        Knuth's *Algorithm Q*.  Quicksort takes *O(n lg n)* average time.  This implementation uses median selection to avoid its *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* worst-case behavior.
>
> The **`heapsort()`** function is an implementation of J.W.J. William's "heapsort" algorithm, a variant of selection sorting; in particular, see D.E. Knuth's *Algorithm H*.
>        Heapsort takes *O(n lg n)* worst-case time.  Its only advantage over **`qsort()`** is that it uses almost no additional memory; while **`qsort()`** does not allocate memory, it is
>        implemented using recursion.
>
> The function **`mergesort()`** requires additional memory of size **`nel * width`** bytes; it should be used only when space is not at a premium.  The **`mergesort()`** function is optimized for data with pre-existing order; its worst case time is *O(n lg n)*; its best case is *O(n)*.
>
> Normally, **`qsort()`** is faster than **`mergesort()`** which is faster than **`heapsort()`**.  Memory availability and pre-existing order in the data can make this untrue.

There are plenty of open source C libraries for you to look at if you want to see specific details of the implementation.

As far as 'why did system X choose algorithm Y', that's a pretty tough question to answer meaningfully - if you're not lucky enough to find a rationale in the documentation, you'd have to ask the designers directly.

Comment: I believe OSX is unique in that heapsort and mergesort are included. The two machines I work on and my uni server lack anything but qsort and qsort_r. Also, I know the question is rather difficult to ask because it involves a lot of history, maybe some politics, definitely some intimate understanding of various systems and a lot of reading. This is the kind of question that if it weren't finals week, I would probably try to answer on my own. But even then, it is a lot to research. My hope was that someone out there had a passion for this answer themselves at an earlier point in time.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite possible.  My point is mostly that outside of the documentation or looking at the implementation you care about directly, there's not much information to go on.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I was hoping if there was any decision making made in a public mailing lists or what have you that someone out there would remember the decision process and provide insight.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick scan in the C11 standard about [qsort()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) and I couldn't find any reference about how `qsort()` should be implemented 
and the expected time/space complexity of the algorithm. All it has to say was about certain conditions about the comparator 
function.

What that means is an implementation can choose *any* comparator based algorithm that fits with qsort(). For example, an implementation can choose to use a naive algorithm such as **[bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)** to implement qsort() which is not as efficient as the real **[quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)**. Bottom line is that it's upto the implementation to decide on the actual algorithm.

Comment: The important thing to derive from reading the standard is that `qsort` has no interface to report failure and thus is not allowed to return without sorting the input. This basically restricts implementors to either using in-place algorithms, or providing a fallback in-place algorithm when memory allocation fails.